# Bugarth - Celtic, Old Norse, both or neither?

Tags: old-norse, celtic

The placename 'bugarth' or 'bugardie' in Shetland has be confused.

Normally for Shetland placenames I turn to Jakobsen who gives: **bu** *stock of cattle on a farm* from [Old Norse] **bú**; and **gart** *an enclosed, uncultivated patch of land* from [Old Norse] **garðr** *an enclosure*.

However, James [Brittonic Language in the Old North](https://spns.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Alan_James_Brittonic_Language_in_the_Old_North_BLITON_Volume_II_Dictionary_2019_Edition.pdf) suggests this could come from the [Early Celtic] ***bou-cc-ā-garto-** *A cattle-yard, an enclosure, pen or fold for livestock*.

Could these two words:

- stem from the same PIE root, and survived relatively unskathed
- have been borrowed one from the other, making one or both of the etymologies dubious
- have been borrowed from a non-IE language (perhaps in Shetland or other point of contact) into both Early Celtic and Old Norse

Or is there another explanation of how these two similar sounding words can have such similar meanings with apparently vastly different origins?

Comment: *-gard* and varaints feature prominently in Norse place names. I cannot say the same about Celtic, but I don't know any Celtic, anyway. // I know the German family name *Baumgard*, with *Baum* "tree". There's *bu-* in German coastal placenames where it apparently relates to *beech*, MHG *Buche*, see the quoted text over at german.SE/[Woher kommt das Wort Eitz](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/54263/35977) (well it's with umlaut, *Bötz, Bütz*, but let's not be picky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could these two words:
>
> - stem from the same PIE root, and survived relatively unskathed
> - have been borrowed one from the other, making one or both of the etymologies dubious
> - have been borrowed from a non-IE language (perhaps in Shetland or other point of contact) into both Early Celtic and Old Norse

Yes indeed! All three are plausible on the surface (as in, all three of these things happened for various words in various languages); in this specific instance, I think it's a mixture of the second plus a healthy dose of coincidence.

The PIE root for "cow" is reconstructed as **gʷṓws*; in various languages, including P-Celtic, P-Italic, and some varieties of Greek, `*gʷ` becomes `/b/`. This is why we see Latin *bōs* (*), Old Irish *bó*, Ancient Greek *boûs*, and so on. This is the first part of the proposed Celtic origin.

But this shift (the "Q-to-P shift") did *not* happen in Germanic, which is why we see the English word "cow" from the same root, with a `/k/`. Instead, Germanic had a presumably unrelated root **būą* "building", which gives Old Norse *bú* and all its descendants. This is the first part of the proposed Germanic origin.

Meanwhile, Germanic also had a root **gardô* (and/or **gardaz*), "fence, enclosure, yard". This is the origin of English "yard" and "garden", via two different paths, and became enormously popular in Romance, completely displacing native Latin words like *hortus*. So it was clearly a popular word in Germanic, and it's not much of a stretch to imagine it being borrowed into Celtic languages too. This seems to be the last part of both reconstructions.

As for which one is correct—I'm afraid I don't know enough to say. It's not inconceivable that both the Celtic root for "cow" and the Germanic root for "building" influenced the name of the location, but it would require someone more familiar with the history of Britain to say for sure.

(*) Latin is not in fact a P-Italic language, but it has lots of loans from Oscan and Umbrian, which were. The word for "cow" seems to be one of them.

Comment: Cow is derived from the observation of the animal chewing (kauen in German). While German bauen (to build) comes from IE like Hindi भू (bhoo) for land/earth/soil. Farmer (Bauer in German) shows the profession and the oxen (bu) helped him work the land and ‘anbauen’ (grow) vegetables.

Comment: Bhoo (land) compared to B-hawa means ‘by sky’ which should be interpreted as વધારો (Vadhārō) meaning ‘raise’ (like feather and father) and this shows the act (by sky) of growing seeds. Feather in context of birds and father in context of births. Birds and births? Both related to breath. There is parallel use of the same roots to show mnemonics in metaphoric use of meanings that can be captured in slightly different but still recognizable groups of consonants within words  that have a common origin that aurpases any written evidence we know.

Comment: I can confirm that "Wieder-Käuer" denotes bovines. This is however not enough to reconstruct an original sense and might a secondary development or even a reinterpretation from a non-PIE borrowing. While it rings true with me that "parallel use" can escape observation or show a deeper meaning, the existence of word play makes it very suspect to missinterpretation.

Comment: @vectory You say ‘Wieder-Kaüer’. Wieder (return/turn/again) is cognate with the Widder not in meaning but in description where Widder describes the form of its horns. Wetter is a similar cognate not in meaning but in description of the returning time (weather is temps in French which also means time). Weather tells us the seasons return. As such a root can be found in different meanings. The last syllables (-der/-ther) show the verb ‘dreh’ (turn)

Comment: Wi- Wea- and Wie- (first syllables) are also found in ‘woman’ and ‘west’. They are antonyms of man and east and show a rudimentary meaning of ‘opposite’. To turn in these three words is described as ‘opposite turn’ ‘w-dreh’.

Answer (score -3):

The Celts and the Norwegians were not the first peoples to have ox gardens so both are cognates and the name is a compound of the phonemes that appear in both languages. The phonemes in the name represent two words meaning ‘bovine garden’ and this gives two etymologies to pursue. 
You could investigate the oldest maps of Shetland and see what spelling is used. I assume the spelling that is closest to either gives you the people who named it Bugarth. Probably Old Norse. There is a Dutch surname called Boogerd. The two phoneme groups Bu and Garth are quite universal in Europe for bovine garden as French ‘bouef cour’ shows.

Comment: Can you explain the putative IE roots and how the known fact of sound changes into Norse and Celtic is consistent with the proposed development?

Comment: That is a lot of questions in one line. For the first part of the question if you wish to look into the IE direction we can decompound words like garden and create to करो हाथों (karo haathon) from a meaning ‘to do/act (by) the hand(s)’. This ‘acting hand’ description is literally compounded in ‘create’ but is in extension used in the word garden, which is in the context of the ‘acting hand’ in earth. I’d like to mention ‘karate’ (the act of the hand I. Sports) and ‘guard’ (the act of the hand in protection). Do you wish for an analyses of ‘kr’ into words based on ‘k’ and ‘r’ and their meanings

Comment: Maybe you should turn your question into a question on SE?

Comment: Gujarati has બીજ કરે તે Bīja karē tē. उगना (ugana) meaning ‘to grow’ is cognate with Hebrew גַן (gn) meaning ‘garden’. અધિનિયમ (land) and germinate show a relation with કાર્ય જમીન હાથ (Kārya jamīna hātha) which means work land hand.

Comment: Focus on the sound laws in question.

Comment: _Karate_ has a well-established etymology in Japanese: _kara_ 'air, 'empty', _te_ 'hand'.

Comment: No Colin, that is the phonetic spelling using other roots and this other meanings. 上げ られた 腕

Comment: 上げ られた 腕 literally raised (given) arms) Age rareta ude shows the reading of K-R (hand raised) where K equals Kaf in Arabic meaning hand and R equals air/raise and this a ‘given’ gesture of the hand. You can see that tjeword for hand (ude) here is different from the Japanese signs. One reading is descriptive, the other alphabetic (using more sounds in one sign). I mean karate descriptive.

Comment: The fusion of morphemes in Kara (sky) can be seen in a Chinese origin like Ri Chu 日出 for sunrise. The element of meaning that is shared in sky and rise is ‘give day’. Like Chi (give life); Ka (give life and Egyptian hieroglyph of raised arms!); Qi give life energy where Qi resembles 给 Gei (give) phonetically. So the meaning of life was something that was associated with given and this results in use of the phoneme in words for life, giving and hand. And also sky.

Comment: May I ask, do you know a derivation of the name "Gujarati"? By the way, this is not a good place to leave notes, as comments and down-voted answers may be deleted. Your comments are not very helpful for the question anyway; They are hard to follow because the associations that you make are not as obvious as they would need to be; Your writing is too broken, although not a beginners English, to express those concepts that work out better in the symbolic language that you have conceived in your own mind to derive those ideas.

Comment: @vectory, Yes the community trends to downvote my answers, only in the linguistic section of SE. I hope I can help with Gujarati. Maybe you shouldmake it a question. I think you arenot asking for derivation as a linguistic term but as asking for its origin. My best comparative estimated guess would be الأراضي الغربية

Comment: That is Arabic using words I think share roots with Gujarati. Also Greek γη χώρα δυτικά

Comment: I hope you didn't miss the intended irony that Sanskrit *gau, go*, Gujarati *gaya* means "cow". Incidentally *gaya* is the Greek goddess of γη, both "pre-Greek" according to Beekes; And *J* regularly corresponds to the *g* in garden, too. Nevertheless, your answer doesn't really provide an answer to the question about which language gave the name and we won't find it on the other half of the planet. Granted, the rules say one question per thread, and you picked one of the three. But it suffers, technicallyfrom the fact that *create, kare, garden* and maybe *cour* reconstruct different roots...

Comment: @vectory Theu reconstruct to different roots but these different roots reconstruct to the same prehistoric phonemes used for a small range of meanings distributed over related contexts sometimes as metaphores and sometimes as different descriptions or even as antonymic anagrams. Irony aside the connection between both gaya’s Is not incodentally.

Comment: They have a prehistoric comparative etymological relation with the meaning of ‘life’ of which heirs of this meaning are still found in modern languages like Chinese Qi, the Egyptian Ka (bull and analogy of the Ka written with two raised hands (also not incodentally) and Hebrew Chi.

Comment: Cow, gau and go also show this prehistoric relation with life/laufen(to walk) in Germannic languages with gehen/gaan/to go.